# How to get screen pixel color the fastest way (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot, screen-scraping

I know there are few of these "how to get screen pixel color?" questions, but when I try their solutions I'm not getting good enough results.

I'm making an application that detects colors of 4 different pixels again and again and processes results. The problem is that when I try following code it's able to run just few loops per second and I need at least 100 loops per seconds (that means 400 pixel detections per second).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr window);
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr dc, int x, int y);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr window, IntPtr dc);

private Color GetColorAt(int x, int y)
    {
        IntPtr desk = GetDesktopWindow();
        IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(desk);
        int a = (int)GetPixel(dc, x, y);
        ReleaseDC(desk, dc);
        return Color.FromArgb(255, (a >> 0) & 0xff, (a >> 8) & 0xff, (a >> 16) & 0xff);
    }

private void record()
    {
        sw.Start();
        while(isRunning)
        {
            Color cK1 = GetColorAt(1857, 488);
            Color cK2 = GetColorAt(1857, 556);
            Color cM1 = GetColorAt(1857, 624);
            Color cM2 = GetColorAt(1857, 692);

            if (cK1.R + cK1.G + cK1.B > 750 && !k1pressed)
            {
                k1pressed = true;
                addEvent("DOWN", "K1");
            }
            else if (cK1.R + cK1.G + cK1.B < 30 && k1pressed)
            {
                k1pressed = false;
                addEvent("UP", "K1");
            }

            if (cK2.R + cK2.G + cK2.B > 750 && !k2pressed)
            {
                k2pressed = true;
                addEvent("DOWN", "K2");
            }
            else if (cK2.R + cK2.G + cK2.B < 30 && k2pressed)
            {
                k2pressed = false;
                addEvent("UP", "K2");
            }

            if (cM1.R + cM1.G + cM1.B > 750 && !m1pressed)
            {
                m1pressed = true;
                addEvent("DOWN", "M1");
            }
            else if (cM1.R + cM1.G + cM1.B < 30 && m1pressed)
            {
                m1pressed = false;
                addEvent("UP", "M1");
            }

            if (cM2.R + cM2.G + cM2.B > 750 && !m2pressed)
            {
                m2pressed = true;
                addEvent("DOWN", "M2");
            }
            else if (cM2.R + cM2.G + cM2.B < 30 && m2pressed)
            {
                m2pressed = false;
                addEvent("UP", "M2");
            }
            labelStatus.Text = "Recording: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

For explanation, my application captures 4 pixels and each of these pixels represents one (virtual) keyboard key or mouse buttons (let's say A,B,LMB,RMB) and addEvent(str, str) just puts information about key being pressed or released into string and after recording is stopped it saves the string into file.

Is there any way I could do something like this 100 times per second? Because I thought operating with just 4 pixels should be really fast..

Comment: There's no point in doing it at a higher rate than your video refresh rate.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of problems with your code.

1. You should not use a loop with DoEvents.  Try an `async` function that awaits `Task.Yield` then calls itself, or in older versions of .NET, a function that uses `BeginInvoke` on itself, etc.
2. Don't update the label so often, that's really slow.
3. Get the desktop window and create the DC just once, then get all the pixel values, as many times as you need them.  Only release the DC when you're done watching the screen.

For example:

```
private Color GetColorAt(IntPtr dc, int x, int y)
{
    int a = (int)GetPixel(dc, x, y);
    return Color.FromArgb(a | 0xFF000000);
}

double lastTextBoxUpdate;
private async void record()
{
    IntPtr desk = GetDesktopWindow();
    IntPtr dc = GetWindowDC(desk);

    sw.Start();
    lastTextBoxUpdate = 0.0;
    while(isRunning)
    {
        Color cK1 = GetColorAt(dc, 1857, 488);
        Color cK2 = GetColorAt(dc, 1857, 556);
        Color cM1 = GetColorAt(dc, 1857, 624);
        Color cM2 = GetColorAt(dc, 1857, 692);

        // ...

        double currentElapsed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        if (currentElapsed > lastTextBoxUpdate + 500) {
            labelStatus.Text = "Recording: " + currentElapsed.ToString();
            lastTextBoxUpdate = currentElapsed;
        }
        await Task.Yield();
    }
    ReleaseDC(desk, dc);
}
```

In addition, it might actually be faster to blit the bounding rectangle into a local bitmap, call `LockBits` on the bitmap, and read the values from there.  This is because accessing graphics memory from the CPU has a high cost to set up the transfer, and a low cost for sending additional data.

Comment: I know DoEvents() is not correctly used in this case and changing the label.Text is also pretty often but I need to keep track of time when my program is running.. Could you explain or link how to make "async fynction" and how to use LockBits? I could not find any simple way to use LockBits and return System.Drawing.Color...

Comment: @user3043260: LockBits returns a structure with a pointer to the data.  If you cast that pointer to `int*`, you can subscript it like an array, and you'll get the same value resulting from p/invoking GetPixel.

Comment: @user3043260: I added an example of how you could implement the three bullet points.

Comment: I see, it looks like it could possibly work really well, thanks for putting there the example. You're right I slowed the function unnecessarily down by generating 4 DCs instead of just 1.. But doesn't Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds return long?

And do you have any advice how could I possibly get information about certain pixel straight from graphic card memory? Because that should be much faster than taking it from screen...

Comment: @user3043260: You can use either `double` or long, doesn't matter.  Stopwatch should be able to measure fractions of milliseconds, but you'd need to use a different property, and it isn't important for our purposes anyway.  When people talk about "reading from the screen" they mean GPU memory... you can't read back from the actual display AT all, only from the GPU buffer that produces the signal to the display.  But GPU memory is connected to the GPU, not the CPU, so reading it from the CPU has high overhead.  That's why making a copy in CPU memory may be advantageous.

Comment: Oh I see, is there any simple tutorial on how to get those results I'm looking for? I mean to get fast function that returns color of one pixel on screen.. Except for this GetPixel one..